# htaccess redirect only main directory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a list of around 800 single redirects, the .htaccess file is in my subdomain directory.

I'm using the syntax: 
`Redirect 301 oldURL newURL`

I need to do this redirect:

http://testsub.example.com/en >>> http://www.example.com/page/

Using this string

```
Redirect 301 /en http://www.example.com/page/
```

All the other url using the same structure are affected, causing errors.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to do that specific redirect or that for 800 subdomains but not others?

Comment: thanks @Dammeul I need to redirect only the redirect in the example. The others are written line by line using Redirect 301 oldURL newURL.

Comment: and this .htaccess is in the root of 'testsub' ... are the other redirects for 'testsub' as well / are they in different subdomain root .htaccess'?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/page/ [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have a new issue you should ask a new question.